# How to return the textbook so it is not set to null?

Tags: java, bluej

I'm still new to Java, currently using BlueJ.

The first method is from class Library and works fine:

```
public TextBook borrowBook(LibraryCard card){

    TextBook book = null;
    if ( (nextBook < bookShelf.length)  && !card.expired() ) {
        book = bookShelf[ nextBook ];
        bookShelf[ nextBook ] = null;
        nextBook++;
        card.swipe();
    }
    return book;
}
```

The second is from class Student and I can not figure out how to change book from null to the book taken off the bookshelf( an array of TextBook objects):

```
public void study()
{
    if( book == null ){
          library.borrowBook(card);
          return book;
    }            
    else{
        if( !book.isFinished() ){
          book.readNextChapter();
        }
        else{
          library.returnBook(book);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void study()
{
    if( book == null ){
          library.borrowBook(card);
          return book;
    }            
    else{
        if( !book.isFinished() ){
          book.readNextChapter();
        }
        else{
          library.returnBook(book);
        }
    }

}
```

First of all, the return type of the function is `void` hence your function should not return anything. Currently there is a `return book` in your function.

Now correct me if I'm wrong. I think this is what you want to achieve:

```
public void study() {
    if(book == null) {
        book = library.borrowBook(card);
    } else {
        if(!book.isFinished()) {
            book.readNextChapter();
        } else {
            library.returnBook(book);
        }
    }
}
```

Since `library.borrowBook(card);` returns the borrowed book, just assign it to `book`. Also, always write clean code (correct indention, consistent position of curly braces, and, remove unnecessary spaces, and etc...). Clean code is good code. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the help, and also thanks for the pointers, my lecturer is always on us about writing clean code haha!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

From the information, I have...

You probably have a Main class, where actions are taking place.

The book (textbook) is going to be null in the following cases:

- if `nextbook > bookshelf.length`
- `card` is expired

Basically, method doesn't get inside the "if" braces and returns null.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your `study` method has a problem you are returning an object in the `study` method which is a void method, this will result in compilation errors.

Assuming that you want to assign the `book` variable to the return value of `library.borrowBook(card)` then you need to assign the like `book=library.borrowBook(card)` and remove the return statement.

So your code should be as below.

```java
public void study(){
    if( book == null ){
          book = library.borrowBook(card);
    }else{
        if( !book.isFinished() ){
          book.readNextChapter();
        }else{
          library.returnBook(book);
        }
    }
}
```